# Re.sub not working for me

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get `re.sub` to replace a pattern specified with a value for example

```
for lines in f:
    pattern='\${2}'+key[0]+'\${2}'
    re.search(pattern,lines)
```

this return the line where the pattern was found. For example this is one of the test returns if got

this is a $$test$$

The problem i'm having is when i do the following

```
re.sub(pattern,key[1],lines)
```

nothing happens. What am i missing? For more info `key[0]=test` and `key[1]=replace`
so what i'm trying to do is whenever "$$test$$" is encountered it will replace it with "replace". I have no problem finding "$$test$$" but for some reason `re.sub` isn't replacing it.

Comment: When you need to store a backslash in a string it's better to use the double backslash form. In your case it works anyway in Python because the dollar sign has no special meaning when prefixed with a backslash and because Python in that case maintains both chars, but in other languages writing `'\$'` is going to mean just `'$'`. When someone is reading a string and finds a backslash expects something special or another backslash. If you need many backslashes in a string then you should use use a raw string...

Comment: For people landing here with general `re.sub` problems, [make sure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813265/why-doesnt-ignorecase-flag-re-i-work-in-re-sub) you are passing `re.IGNORECASE` as a `flags=` argument, not the `count` argument.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You *are* assigning the result of `re.sub` back to a variable, right?  e.g.

```
lines = re.sub(pattern, key[1], lines)
```

It's a string, so it can't be changed (strings are immutable in Python), therefore a new string is created and returned to you. If you don't assign it back to a name, you will lose it.

Comment: ahhh i thought that it replaced it. how would i go about replacing this line in a file? btw thanks for this. I can't believe this didn't occur to me

Comment: In a file, you're going to read each line from an input file and write it to an output file; at the end, if you want, delete the original file and rename the output file. Or if the file will fit into memory, you can read it into memory entirely, do your changes, and write it back out to the same file. There are many examples on SO and elsewhere on the Web for doing this in Python.

Comment: Thanks so much. You've been a great help.

Comment: In the interesting of keeping related questions/answers linked, I'll post this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598121/re-sub-not-working-for-me-with-python

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text, you can run re.sub() directly on the whole text as follows:

```
import re

ss = '''that's a line
another line
a line to $$test$$
123456
here $$test$$ again
closing line'''

print(ss,'\n')

key = {0:'test', 1:'replace'}

regx = re.compile('\$\${[0]}\$\$'.format(key))

print( regx.sub(key[1],ss) )
```

.

If you read a file, you should have interest to read the whole file and put it in an object **ss** before runing re.sub() on it, instead of reading and replacing line after line

.

And if you have a list of lines , you must process as follows:

```
import re

key = {0:'test', 1:'replace'}

regx = re.compile('\$\${[0]}\$\$'.format(key))

lines = ["that's a line",
         'another line',
         'a line to $$test$$',
         '123456',
         'here $$test$$ again',
         'closing line']

for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    lines[i] =  regx.sub(key[1],line)
```

Otherwise a line containing '$$test$$' wouldn't be modified:

```
import re

key = {0:'test', 1:'replace'}

regx = re.compile('\$\${[0]}\$\$'.format(key))

lines = ["that's a line",
         'another line',
         'a line to $$test$$',
         '123456',
         'here $$test$$ again',
         'closing line']

for line in lines:
    line =  regx.sub(key[1],line)


print (lines)
```

result

```
["that's a line", 'another line', 'a line to $$test$$', '123456', 'here $$test$$ again', 'closing line']
```