# re.sub Not working for me with python

Tags: python

I have the following text in a text file:

```
"&amp;
ALIGN="left"
COMSTOCK OIL &amp; GAS, LP

ALIGN="right"
170040

ALIGN="left"
WOLFBONE (TREND AREA)&amp;"
```

The following is my code after importing everything:

```
text_file = open("pages.txt", "r")
page = text_file.read()

regextext = "&amp;"
pattern1 = re.compile(regextext)
search1 = re.findall(pattern1, page)
print search1

re.sub("&amp;",'',page)
print page

search1 = re.findall(pattern1, page)
print search1
```

It isn't stripping out the "&". The findall finds all the instance but the re.sub() isn't doing its job. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to re-assign it back to `page`:

```
page = re.sub("&amp;",'',page)
```

Comment: In the interesting of keeping related questions/answers linked, I'll post this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033375/re-sub-not-working-for-me

Answer (score 3):

[re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) does not perform the substitution in-place. It returns a new string with the result of the substitution. You are free to reassign to the original variable name if you like, of course.

So what you want is

```
page = re.sub("&amp;", '', page)
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet it does it`s job, the only thing you need to fix is to print not the old version of the text, stored in variable "page", but a new one< stored in a new variable, like this:

```
new_text = re.sub('&', '', page)
print new_text
```