# Python re.sub replace html attributes

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to resize images from html code. This is one example:

My goal is to substitute `" height="108"` " and `" width="150"` with height and width 400.
I've tried the following lines, though they don't seem to work:

```
re.sub(r'width="[0-9]{2,4}"','width="400"',x)
re.sub(r'height="[0-9]{2,4}"','height="400"',x)
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Ps: I'm not that good at Regex... :)

Comment: Nooo... Do not parse/modify html/xml with regexes... Use tools like BeautifulSoup/XSLT/...

Comment: That does not quite answer my question, though i'll have a look into it :)

Comment: Python strings are immutable. The sub function returns a new string

Comment: Regexes are fine for this particular use case.

Comment: What @cricket_007 said. Just add `x=` to the beginning of those lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Re.sub not working for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033375/re-sub-not-working-for-me)

Comment: Wow, I just realized how retarded I am, or not, I mean the regex was correct at least (/ _ \)

Comment: Always worth a try here first https://regex101.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it does not work is **because strings are immutable**, and you do not process the result. You can "*solve*" the issue with:

```
x = re.sub(r'width="[0-9]{2,4}"','width="400"',x)
x = re.sub(r'height="[0-9]{2,4}"','height="400"',x)
```

That being said **it is a very bad idea to process HTML/XML with regexes**. Say you have a tag `<foo altwidth="1234">`. Now you will change it to `<foo altwidth="400">` do you want that? Probably not.

You can for instance use *BeautifulSoup*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(x,'lxml')

for tag in soup.findAll(attrs={"width":True})
    tag.width = 400
for tag in soup.findAll(attrs={"height":True})
    tag.height = 400
x = str(soup)
```

Here we substitute **all** tags with a `width` attribute to `width="400"` and all tags with a `height` with `height="400"`. You can make it more advanced by for instance **only accepting `<img>` tags**, like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(x,'lxml')

for tag in soup.findAll('img',attrs={"width":True})
    tag.width = 400
for tag in soup.findAll('img',attrs={"height":True})
    tag.height = 400
x = str(soup)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working fine:

```
>>> x = '<foo width="150" height="108">'
>>> import re
>>> y = re.sub(r'width="[0-9]{2,4}"','width="400"',x)
>>> y
'<foo width="400" height="108">'
```

Note that `re.sub` does not mutate x:

```
>>> x
'<foo width="150" height="108">'
>>> y
'<foo width="400" height="108">'
```

Perhaps you want to do this instead:

```
x = re.sub(r'width="[0-9]{2,4}"','width="400"',x)
x = re.sub(r'height="[0-9]{2,4}"','height="400"',x)
```

Comment: Flagged a duplicate, by the way