# What is the correct way to use a regular expression to replace non-alpha characters at the beginning of a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

NOTE: I have looked at other posts such as "[Re.sub not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033375/re-sub-not-working-for-me)".  This is 1) for a specific pattern and 2) is for matching that specific pattern "anywhere" in a string.  This is different than that post 1) because it is looking for not a specific pattern but non-alphanumeric regular expression and 2) because it is look to replace "specifically" at the beginning of a string.

**I respectfully ask that you please unmark this as duplicate, because it is not.**

I have a method that takes in a string and tries to replace all non-alpha characters at the beginning of the string with a fixed string ("BEGINNING_"), using a Regular Expression...

```
def m_getWebSafeString(self, dirtyAttributeName):
  cleanAttributeName = ''.join(dirtyAttributeName)
  # Deal with beginning of string...
  re.sub('^[^a-zA-z]*','BEGINNING_',cleanAttributeName)
  if "BEGINNING_" in cleanAttributeName:
    print ' -- NEW STRING = {}'.format(cleanAttributeName)
return cleanAttributeName
```

It runs with no errors but does not appear to properly substitute the string.  For example, the IF statement to trigger the print statement does not happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://pythex.org/

Comment: You do not assign the value to the `cleanAttributeName` after cleaning.

Comment: You're doing the substitution, then throwing the result away because you're not storing it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result of `re.sub()` to sth.:

```
def m_getWebSafeString(self, dirtyAttributeName):
  cleanAttributeName = ''.join(dirtyAttributeName)
  # Deal with beginning of string...

  cleanAttributeName = re.sub('^[^a-zA-z]*','BEGINNING_',cleanAttributeName) # ORIGINAL REFERENCE
  # --- ^ --- here

  if "BEGINNING_" in cleanAttributeName:
    print ' -- NEW STRING = {}'.format(cleanAttributeName)
return cleanAttributeName
```