# Proper replacement of "beginning" non-alphanumeric characters, in python, using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

**NOTE:** This post is not the same as the post "[Re.sub not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033375/re-sub-not-working-for-me)".

- That post is about matching and replacing ANY non-alphanumeric substring in a string.
- This question is specifically about matching and replacing non-alphanumeric substrings that explicitly show up at the beginning of a string.

The following method attempts to match any non-alphanumeric character string "AT THE BEGINNING" of a string and replace it with a new string "BEGINNING_"

```
def m_getWebSafeString(self, dirtyAttributeName):
  cleanAttributeName = ''.join(dirtyAttributeName)
  # Deal with beginning of string...
  cleanAttributeName = re.sub('^[^a-zA-z]*',"BEGINNING_",cleanAttributeName)
  # Deal with end of string...
  if "BEGINNING_" in cleanAttributeName:
    print ' ** ** ** D: "{}" ** ** ** C: "{}"'.format(dirtyAttributeName, cleanAttributeName)
```

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:** The method seems to not only replace non-alphnumeric characters but it also incorrectly inserts the "BEGINNING_" string at the beginning of all strings that are passed into it.  In other words...

**GOOD RESULT:** If the method is passed the string `*@#$ThisIsMyString1`, it correctly returns `BEGINNING_ThisIsMyString1`

**BAD/UNWANTED RESULT:** However, if the method is passed the string `ThisIsMyString2` it incorrectly (and always) inserts the replacement string (`BEGINNING_`), even there are no non-alphanumeric characters, and yields the result `BEGINNING_ThisIsMyString2`

**MY QUESTION:** What is the correct way to write the re.sub() line so it only replaces those non-alphnumeric characters at the beginning of the string such that it does not always insert the replacement string at the beginning of the original input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're matching 0 or more instances of non-alphabetic characters by using the `*` quantifier, which means it'll always be picked up by your pattern. You can replace what you have with

```
re.sub('^[^a-zA-Z]+', ...)
```

to ensure that only 1 or more instances are matched.

Comment: That works.  Thanks for the explanation with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
re.sub('^[^a-zA-z]*',"BEGINNING_",cleanAttributeName)
```

with

```
re.sub('^[^a-zA-z]+',"BEGINNING_",cleanAttributeName)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more elegant solution. You can use this

```
re.sub('^\W+', 'BEGINNING_', cleanAttributeName)
```

\W Matches any non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the class [^a-zA-Z0-9_].

```
>>> re.sub('^\W+', 'BEGINNING_', '@#$ThisIsMyString1')
'BEGINNING_ThisIsMyString1'
>>> re.sub('^\W+', 'BEGINNING_', 'ThisIsMyString2')
'ThisIsMyString2'
```